Could not invoke RNFSManager.readFile in ReactNative
I'm trying to read a file with url but I got an error that "Could not invoke RNFSManager.readFile". After that, my app crashed. I could not find why RNFS.readfile caused a crash. RNFS.readfile cause crash.
Here is the code that I implemented
let contentType = obj?.mime;
const imageUrl = store.getState().homeReducer.imageUrl;

let concatingKey = `${imageUrl}${obj?.modificationDate}-${PickImagePath(obj?.path)}`;

let contentDeposition = 'inline;filename="' + obj?.path + '"';

const base64 = await fs.readFile(obj?.path, 'base64');

const arrayBuffer = decode(base64);

s3bucket.createBucket(async () => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: concatingKey,
    Body: arrayBuffer,
    ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
    ContentType: contentType,
  };

on This line const base64 = await fs.readFile(obj?.path, 'base64') cause crash. Not every time. It crashes when I try to upload large data.
Here is the screenshot of the Error

